# CSS styling tables in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, css-tables

I'm using a table for the footer of my web page. I really don't know much about tables because I've always used CSS. The following is the only table I've ever made. It seems to work in Opera, Chrome, and Firefox, but everything goes to the left in IE. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong with the table because I don't know much about tables. Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="framecontentBottom">
<div id="container">
        <div id="row">
<div id="left">

<!-- Counter Code START --><a href="http://www.e-zeeinternet.com/" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.e-zeeinternet.com/count.php?page=760915&style=LED_g&nbdigits=4&reloads=1" alt="Web Counter" border="0" ></a><br><a href="http://www.e-zeeinternet.com/" title="Web Counter" target="_blank" style="font-family: Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; color: #000000; text-decoration: none;">Page Views</a><!-- Counter Code END -->

</div>


    <div id="middle">

Contact me at jacksterdavis<img src="images/@white.png">gmail.com

        </div>
            <div id="right">

            <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
            <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
            <a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
            <a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a>
            <a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a>
            <a class="addthis_button_preferred_4"></a>
            <a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
            <a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-4f302421558e3fc2"></script>
            <!-- AddThis Button END -->

            </div>
        </div>
<div id="row">
<div id="left">
</div>
    <div id="middle">
    <p>The internet is the printing press of the 21'st century.</p>
    </div>
<div id="right">
</div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
#container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    }

  #row  {
    display: table-row;   
    }

#middle {
    width:50%;
    text-align:center;
    display: table-cell;
    }

}
#left
{
   width:25%;
   text-align:left; 
   display: table-cell;
}
#right
{
   width:25%;
   text-align:right; 
   display: table-cell;
   padding: 5px;
}
#quote
{
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
}
#logoBtm
{
    align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}
#logoBtmLeft
{
    align:left;
}
#logoBtmRight
{
    align:right;
}
#framecontentBottom{
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    margin-top: -3em;
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0; 
    height: 80px; /*Height of bottom frame div*/
    overflow: hidden; /*Disable scrollbars. Set to "scroll" to enable*/
    background-color: #585858;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
}
```

If you point out everything wrong with my table it's appreciated, thanks. A CSS fix would be the best but if the HTML must be edited it's fine.

Comment: Can you provide an example with either http://jsbin.com or http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Why are you using table-CSS? Also, what version of IE is running into trouble with your code?

Comment: this is not using a table.  this is using CSS to mimic a table display.  ie 7- doesn't support this, but why use table-display in the  first place? http://caniuse.com/#search=table-cell

Comment: Well, do you know a better alternative for the footer I'm making? I had a hard time making work.

Comment: yes, don't use tables for layout.  use divs that are inline-block or floated.  both have their issues in ie7 but google has many hacks available to you to make it work.

Comment: Thanks. What's the deal with IE7?

Comment: ha.  what isnt the deal with ie7.  Its the second worst browser for CSS support, and sadly, still widely used.  The worst, btw, is ie6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>the problem most likely lies in the fact that you have two divs with the same id.  use classes for row instead.</strike>removed for the comfort of others.  This line doesnt help the solution at hand.

also, in referring to your comment, ie 7 does not support table display CSS.

http://caniuse.com/#search=table-cell

use a combination of inline block or float.  but beware, as inline block has its own issues with ie7

http://flipc.blogspot.com/2009/02/damn-ie7-and-inline-block.html

Here is a working, valid, example.

http://jsfiddle.net/mRHnW/2/

A couple changes:  Ive styled every div inside of `.row` so that it gets applied once (and if it needs to be fixed, it can be, in one place.  Even in CSS, it needs to be [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

I removed the `margin-top` from the `#frameContentBottom` selector because it was screwing with jsfiddle giving me visible results.  Feel free to re-instate it if its important to your layout.

I adjusted the width of your 'columns' to be slightly less than 100%, because you've also included padding.  The way the CSS [Box Model as specified by W3C](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html) works is that the width declaration *does not include padding, border, and margin*.  Thus, if you're creating a 100% div, and want 5px padding, then you need to specify less than 100% to get the padding within the 100% confines.

On a sufficiently wide screen (something bigger than jsfiddle default panes), your footer should look about what you expect.

Comment: That would not affect the CSS capabilities of rendering it, just the semantic meaning of the page.

Comment: Why would classes make a difference?

Comment: having multiple ids in a page is semantically incorrect and will produce unexpected behavior, especially once you introduce JavaScript.  make your ids unique, or use classes.

Comment: Do you think you could help me a little bit with this. I'm not great at HTML or CSS. I have to go so I'll be back on tomorrow.

Comment: I still can't upvote this because of that first line. While multiple IDs may be semantically incorrect and cause problems in JavaScript, it would **not** cause any problems in CSS alone, which is what the problem is about. It's right there at the top, the first thing people will read.

Comment: Ive removed the line, but if it stops people from writing *bad HTML*, Im glad for it.